# Clustering a set of vectors

Tags: clustering

Provided a set ($m$ no. of) of n-dimensional vectors what would be the correct unsupervised approach to cluster them? The vectors essentially represent patterns.

For example:
Set of vector is represented as $V$. Let a vector $v1$ represents a pattern similar to $y = sin(x)$ curve. The $y$ values are stored in $v1$ and the $x$ intervals are same for all the vectors. Similarly there is a vector $v2$ representing pattern similar to $y=log(x)$.

The problem: Does a group of vectors exist, exhibiting similar (not exactly same) pattern as $v1$, similarly for $v2$ and so on?

Therefore these patterns are required to be clustered appropriately. There are methods such as Vector Quantization, but I am not sure if those methods are appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Since Neural Networks can learn any non-linear function, I would go for an Autoencoder for dimensionality reduction first, and then run a k-Means clustering on the encoded features. If a regular (non-linear) pattern in the data exist, an Autoencoder that is "*deep enough*" should be able to account for that.

For the same reasons (i.e. non-linear patterns) I would avoid linear techniques such as PCA.

If this suits you, you can check my Notebooks. I implemented Autoencoders in TensorFlow 1.x [here](https://github.com/IvanBongiorni/TensorFlow_Tutorial/blob/master/TensorFlow_3_Autoencoder_Dimensionality_Reduction.ipynb), and in TensorFlow 2.0 [here](https://github.com/IvanBongiorni/TensorFlow2.0_Tutorial/blob/master/TensorFlow2.0_04_Autoencoder_for_Dimensionality_Reduction.ipynb).

Comment: t-SNE is also a non-linear technique for dimensionality reduction. It's already available in sklearn. If you have enough data, nothing matches the power of Neural Network, but its implementation is certainly quicker.

Comment: So, the purpose of the autoencoder is to reduce the dimension (in this two dimension to a single dimension). Then the 
encoded data can be clustered with suitable clustering method. Did I understand the approach correctly?

Comment: Yes, that would be my approach.

Comment: @Leevo The first comment is "wrong" and better to be fixed/removed. t-SNE is a visualization algorithm and "must not" be used for dimensionality reduction purpose. It is non-parametric and stochastic thus can not be reproduced in same way. UMAP is the right equivalent/alternative for dimensionality reduction.